# How to remove an object in a photo in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, gimp

How to remove an object like stairs from a photo without leaving a missing part in the photo in Inkscape? I'm trying to remove stairs from a photo and then blend it so you can't tell that the stairs were removed in Inkscape.

Answer (score 4):

Inkscape is a vector art tool - your photo is raster - use GIMP for photo-editing.

There are hundreds of tutorials out there for removing items from a photo in GIMP - I'll give you a link here to see one using the method I'll quickly overview herein.

!) If you're unsure of your accuracy, you might either make a layer copy first or limit your area of effect by making a selection with the pen tool so you don't stray out of your target area - I prefer typically to just copy my layer.

Then you use the clone Tool (C on keyboard) and hitting Cntrl whilst left-clicking you choose a source area (where the data is cloned from) and then left-click-and-drag paint over the item you wish to remove.

It's a very manual process, and the intelligence is provided by you, not the tool, so pay attention, give it a try, and save copies of your files (and layers) whilst you're learning how to do this sort of thing!

Hope this helps!

[How to remove anything from a photo in GIMP](https://www.daviesmediadesign.com/how-to-remove-anything-from-a-photo-in-gimp/)